# connect to internet through another computer

Tags: debian, networking

PLEASE EDIT AND IMPROVE :-)

Baffled by most of the documents available on the internet that are supposed to help you set up a network?  Here are some simple step by step instructions to enable access to the internet on a computer connected to another computer (via ethernet cable) when the latter is connected to the internet, and to be able to share files between these computers -- a network!  It took me six days to sort this all out and it's not perfect yet :(

These instructions are for Debian/Stretch machines using the 'nm-connection-editor' which should come with XFCE4; they may be useful on other machines or not.  I presume you know how to install a package, edit a text file, type commands in a terminal, and use a widget/applet in XFCE4.

Our simple network will consist of two computers:  the 'Server' computer is the one connected to the internet and to the other 'Client' computer.  The Server therefore must have two ethernet ports (add one if needed), but the Client need have only one.

Comment: Well that tech jargon is most essential to fulfill your request.  What you're looking for is an howto, not a simple question, which makes it off-topic here.  If you can't follow any of the multiple tutorials found online, you should simply go get a cheap router instead of buying new unnecessary equipment (Ethernet adapter) and wasting all that time to avoid paying 40-50$.

Comment: Oh, and a final note, Windows doesn't automatically (nor automagically) enable connection sharing, but I do agree it's easier to set up for a beginner.

Comment: Yes, perhaps a howto but so far I haven't found a good one thus I ask for a suggestion not a lecture.  It might be easy enough to be answered smimply, I don't know otherwise until I'm told so.  And it it's off topic, the moderators will doubtless let me know.

Comment: Bad news, you have 2 LANs. One has 2 machines on it, your cable or DSL or satellite modem and the computer that is plugged into it. The other LAN is made up of the other computer and the second interface card. The one with the modem will probably be being set up automatically by your ISP, but you will need to set up the second yourself. There are two approaches. 1. You set up one machine to be the master machine (strictly a dhcp server) for the LAN and it sets up the other machines on the LAN. The other way is you set up each machine individually. The latter is usually simpler.

Comment: The first step is to get the two machines talking to each other. I suggest google for `systemd static ip addresses` which will lead to things like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd which tell you how to configure a wired adaptor with a static address. Do this on both machines.  I suggest using addresses 192.168.20.1 and 192.168.20.2 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0, as these are pretty unlikely to conflict with anything else. check you can ping both addresses from both machines, and the machine with 2 interfaces can connect to the world. After that you need to set up NAT.

Comment: Tx. Icarus, I'll read the arch doc, they are almost always the best to be had.

Comment: I do agree with @JuliePelletier, in the short term you would just be better off buying a new router. Long term you will potentially learn a lot from this exercise but you may have frustrations along the way. The NAT only has to be set up on the machine with the 2 interfaces.

Comment: I got my network going and if you're interested I'd like to post how I got it done. Not sure if anyone will read this, tho.

Answer (score 0):

First, the internet connection:

0:  On the Server, at the command line run:

```
$ nmcli device show
```

(If nothing happens you may need to install the 'network-manager' package, it will be needed on both Server and Client.)
... you will see several blocks of data each starting with "GENERAL.DEVICE" simmilar to:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:            enp5s4           <<< You'll need this line.
GENERAL.TYPE:              ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:            00:50:BF:9E:44:2B
GENERAL.MTU:               1500
GENERAL.STATE:             100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:        Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:          /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:  on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:            24.207.17.185/22
IP4.GATEWAY:               24.207.16.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:              dst = 216.104.113.105/32, nh = 24.207.16.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                24.207.0.168
IP4.DNS[2]:                64.178.142.11
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:            fe80::250:bfff:fe9e:442b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

... there must be a block for each ethernet connection, so a minimum of two is needed.  (Note the block beginning with "GENERAL.DEVICE ... lo" DOES NOT COUNT!) Find the block with:

```
"GENERAL.CONNECTION        Wired connection 1"
```

... this is the block describing your internet connection and it should be first on the list.  At the top of that block find the line simmilar to:

```
"GENERAL.DEVICE:            enp5s4"
```

... write it down.  (Or, have a terminal with the above visible as we perform the next steps, that's much better actually.)

For the other blocks write down the lines similar to:

```
"GENERAL.DEVICE:           enp63s0"
GENERAL.CONNECTION:        [ whatever, often nothing ]
```

The rest is done using the applet:

1:  Click on the XFCE4 applet: "Applications" > "Settings" > "Network Connections"

... or just run 'nm-connection-editor' from the command line.  (If nothing happens you may need to install the 'network-manager-gnome' package, as I did on both computers.)

Settings made in the applet are as follows:

2:  Highlight "Wired connection 1" (the default name of your internet connection) and click on "Edit" (or just double click).

3:  "Ethernet" tab > "Device" > Click on the pulldown arrow and select the 'enp5s4' syle string that you just found within the same block as "Wired connection 1" above.  (It will be a longer string here like "enp5s4 (00:50:BF:9E:44:2B)", but that's ok).

4:  Click "Save", you will be returned to the "Network Connections" box.

5:  Click "Add" (unless there is already a second connection shown in which case click "Edit" and go to step "8").

6:  Select "Ethernet" from the pulldown list (but it should be there by default anyway).

7:  Click "Create".

8:  The default "Connection name" is: "Ethernet connection 1", but you can change it to something simpler like "Eth1" (which we assume here).

9:  Repeat step "3" but now choose the other 'enp63s0' style string that was NOT found in the same block with 'Wired connection 1' above.

10: "IPv4 Settings" tab > "Method" > Click on the pulldown arrow and select: "Shared to other computers".

11:  Click "Save".

12:  Close the applet.

13:  Go to the Client computer.

14:  Repeat steps 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  (You're connection here should have exactly the same information as the "Wired connection 1" connection you made on the Server, except for the different 'enp5s4' style string which will be the correct one for this machine.)

15:  Click "Save"

16:  Close the applet.

17:  At command line: (still on the Client computer) run:

```
$ nmcli -p con up "Wired connection 1"
```

... This should make the connection.

```
$ nmcli -t -f STATE general
```

... You should see 'connected' in green.  If you do, you should be connected to the internet.  (Of course you can go back and rename any connection you want.  "Wired connection 1" might be shortened to "Wired1", or something.)

===========================================================

Now to enable filesharing:

Install (if needed) packages 'nfs-common' and 'nfs-kernel-server' on both machines.
(Note, I got an error on instalation but it seemed not to matter.)

0:  Go to the Client computer.

1:  Run:

```
$ nmcli device show
```

... and write down the line simmilar to:

```
"IP4.ADDRESS[1]: ... 10.42.0.25/24"
```

Ignore anything from the slash forward, the string you want in this example is: "10.43.0.25".

2:  Go to the Server, edit the file '/etc/exports'.  You will add a line to it that consists of whatever part of your filesystem you want to share with the Client followed by the IP4.ADDRESS (that you just wrote down) of the Client.  For example, to make your entire filesystem visible to the Client:

```
"/ 10.42.0.25"
```

... to make just some directory named "/shared" visible to the Client:

```
"/shared 10.42.0.25"
```

Obviously, whatever you want to share with the Client will have to be copied to "/shared" -- this seems to be the normal thing since the rest of the Server's filesystem is preserved untouchable. There is much fine tuning possible, eg:

```
"/shared 10.42.0.25(rw,sync,no_root_squash)"
```

... for more information run:

```
$ man exports
```

The Client can read and copy files from the Server, but not alter them or add anything since by default the Server's files are 'read only' to the Client.

3:  Save the file.

4:  Run:

```
$ /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

5:  Repeat step "1" above to get the IP4.ADDRESS of the Server.  (Note, be sure the IP address you use is the one for the cable to the Client (named "Eth1" in this example) NOT the one for the connection to the internet (named "Wired connection 1" by default)).

6:  Go to the Client.

7:  Create a directory (or use an existing one) anywhere you want that will be the 'mount point' for the shared files on the Server.  For example:

```
$ mkdir /Network_mountpoint
```

8:  Edit the file "/etc/fstab".

In keeping with the above examples, add this line to it:

```
"10.42.0.1:/shared  /Network_mountpoint  nfs rsize=8192, wsize=8192, timeo=60, retry=6, retrans=6, intr, nofail"
```

This gives the IP4.ADDRESS of the connection on the Server (that you saved above) followed by the 'sharing' directory named "/shared", followed by the directory where the shared files will be mounted (i.e. made accessible to the Client) named "/Network_mountpoint", followed by the filesystem type (nfs = network filesystem), followed by various recommended tweeks.  (Note, be sure to include "nofail" above, otherwise your Client computer will refuse to boot if the Server is not running or its network is down -- it will keep looking for the network forever which seems a bit stupid to me.  Also, if the tweeks are not exactly right, if the Server is turned off, the Client might panic and start sending you an enless stream of " ... not reponding, timed out" messages and only a power off restart will fix it -- which also seems a bit stupid to you and me, but what do we know?)

9:  Save the file.

10:  Run:

```
$ mount -a
$ /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
```

... and you should be able to view anything in the "/shared" directory of the Server as if it was actually in "/Network_mountpoint" on the Client. (Note, I needed to reboot the Client first, I haven't figured out why yet.)

Note, if you make any changes to "/etc/exports" on the Server, you will probably get a message on the Client: "Stale File Handle".  If so, on the Client, run:

```
$ umount /Network_mountpoint
$ mount -a
$ /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
```

===========================================================

Useful commands:

```
$ networkctl list
$ /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
$ /etc/init.d/rpcbind restart
$ restart systemd-networkd.service
$ systemctl status systemd-networkd
$ nmcli
$ ping (any address shown in 'nmcli device show')
```

For more information see the excellent:

http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-Between-Linux-Computers-Using-NFS